# Slow compilation of any asp.net mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I'm developing a web application based on Umbraco CMS (Asp.Net Mvc 5).

Typical view in my project contains several different partial views.
Unfortunately I noticed that **first request** to any page with any unique partial view (which wasn't compiled earlier) takes too much time.

I measured **IView.Render** method execution time and it runs ~4 sec.
After some deep debugging I found that regardless of the view content (I tried even with empty views) compilation time directly depends on "referenced assemblies" number in the project.

In my project I have ~120 referenced assemblies and that's why **CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile** (method responsible for view compilation) executes ~4 sec for any view.

**Do I have any chances to solve this problem without mvc views precompilation?**

I tried RazorGenerator library and it compiles all my views really fast but I don't want to loose dynamic compilation benefits.

Does MVC use some not optimal algorithm for the compilation (RazorGenerator compiles much faster) ?

Reducing the number of referenced assemblies is not possible in my case.

[Here is a screenshot of my debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZIFy.png)

Comment: Maybe try using `RenderPartial ` ?

Comment: @Hackerman I've been using RenderPartial method already.

Comment: Try compiling on release mode instead of debug

Comment: Why do you have `120 referenced assemblies`? Thats way too high.

Comment: @Hackerman I tried, there was not much difference

Comment: @ViVi Project quite big and has many nuget-packages included. I found that all referenced assemblies comes from [BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getreferencedassemblies.aspx) method